# VS2015+Xamarin Does not recognize that emulator started

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android

my Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin is not recognizing that my android emulator started, it was working just fine in the last days, and it just stopped after I restarted the computer today.

Here is the Output log:

```
1>Starting deploy API19-Intel_Atom ...
1>Starting emulator API19-Intel_Atom ...
1>C:\Users\Kyore\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd API19-Intel_Atom -prop monodroid.avdname=API19-Intel_Atom
1>Hax is enabled
1>Hax ram_size 0x20000000
1>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
1>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
1>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

It just get stuck in that line, the emulator starts normally, it is fast and I can open/close things without problems, so I have to press CTRL+BREAK to stop it:

```
1>Process was cancelled
1>Start emulator API19-Intel_Atom was cancelled.
1>Process was cancelled
Build has been canceled.
```

I tried to restart the computer, restarted VS, restarted ADB server, decreased emulator RAM and HAXM RAM, it always happen.

Comment: Do you see the emulator listed when you run `adb devices`?

Comment: Yes, it shows up on adb devices

Answer (score 0):

Try run Visual Studio with Administrator privilege.

> "Run as Administrator"

If that's not working, try

- Clear AVD cache, Xamarin cache.
- Clean the project `right click on solution in VS -> Clean Solution`.
- Delete `bin/obj` folders in you project folder manually for e.g.
  `../MyXamarinProject/bin`, `../MyXamarinProject/obj`
- Create new `Android Virtual Device`